# How align Image on right side of div?

Tags: css, html

I am making one div in that I want to align image on right of that div and fill up color of same image on other remaining free place of div but image is not aligning right to it.
The main problem is that I don't want to use `<img>` tag inside div, I want to to use image as background image of that div and that also should be right align.

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/V5dH2/)

code :

```
<div class="inq_parent">
        <div class="inq_header">

        </div>
</div>

.inq_parent
{
    height:560px;
    width:90%;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:5%;
}
.inq_header
{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9be2.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `background-position:right;`

```
.inq_header
{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9be2.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:right;
    text-align:right;
}
```

or in short

```
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9be2.png) no-repeat right;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OgIDeJiy/3/)**

---

Updated

```
.inq_header
{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    background:#333333 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9be2.png) no-repeat right;

}
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ArObijO/2/)**

Comment: @Sowmya : getting problem here http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/V5dH2/1/, is show color problem here, Image aligned but other area colored with parent div's color.

Comment: @Sowmya : Are you there ?

Comment: @user3145373 remove `background-color:#333333` and add like this `background:#333333 url(http://i.stack.imgur.com/x9be2.png) no-repeat right;`